# Animation linkBorderHover is not working with ::after / ::before elements?

Tags: css, css-animations

I tried to make animation for link on hover using `::after`, `::before` elements and `::after` element just disappears and that's all. I don't understand where is the problem?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zx8t2a1p/) with my code.

Comment: There's no actual keyframe animation on your example, what would you like it to do?

Comment: You haven't declared what the `linkBorderHover` animation is. You're trying to use it, but it doesn't exist in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this

```
a::after,
a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  height: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover::after {
  animation: linkBorderHover 8s forwards ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes linkBorderHover {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I got it now how animation works, need to add `keyframes`. Thanks!